Отсутствует файл php.ini под Windows
Делаю работу на php и postgresql. Не могу реализовать подключение к бд, файл  psql есть, но не могу найти файл php.ini. Зашёл в phpinfo и увидел в строке это:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   no value
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)

как быть? что с этим делать?

Зависит от того, как было установлено PHP и на какую систему.  Самое простое скопировать отсюда https://github.com/php/php-src  файл php.ini-development или php.ini-production и переименовать.  Ну скопировать видимо в /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Обычно php.ini находится в /etc/php/VERSION/apache2/php.ini при установке пыхи

а система-то какая? виндоуз? линукс? Макинтош?

у меня стоит windows 11

Зайти в папку, в которой установлен РНР, и переименовать файл php.ini-development в php.ini

Да, всё получилось! Спасибо большое

Я переименовал файл php.ini-development, убрал ( ; ) перед всеми упоминаниями pgsql

Напишите ответ на свой вопрос. Фокусируясь на php.ini
